# Icon on checkBox Button

Tags: c#, winforms, button, checkbox

I wanted to put iconic symbol on my button(it is checkBox,but appearance like button) in Visual Studio 2010,c#.So can any one tell me how to do so??

Comment: What do you mean by checkbox, which has appearance like button?

Comment: @Maresh There's a `winforms` tag.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I assume the OP means it's a `CheckBox` with it's `Appearance` set to `Appearance.Button`. (Right?)

Comment: Yes,i am using Windows Forms CheckBox control as a Button.

Answer (score 2):

set the Image property or by code like this `button.Image = new Bitmap("Click.jpg");`

Comment: But i wanted to put Icon,not image

Answer (score 2):

Select `Image` property of checkbox. Choose `Local resource > Import` and navigate to your icon file. By default icon files will not be shown, so you need to select `All Files (*.*)` filter.

If you want to set icon from code, you can do it this way:

```
checkBox.Image = new Icon(pathToIconFile).ToBitmap();
```

UPDATE: You can't zoom or stretch image, which assigned via `Image` property. In this case you need to use `BackgrounImage` property instead:

```
checkBox.BackgroundImage = new Icon(pathToIconFile).ToBitmap();
checkBox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Also you can resize image programmatically, or draw it manually in `OnPaint` method, but it will take more efforts.

UPDATE: Resizing image

```
public static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, Size size)
{            
    Bitmap result = new Bitmap(size.Width, size.Height);

    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(result))
    {                
        graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, result.Width, result.Height);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```
const int padding = 6;
Size size = new Size(checkBox.Width - padding, checkBox.Height - padding);
checkBox.Image = ResizeImage(new Icon(pathToIconFile).ToBitmap(), size);
```

Comment: Thanks it will might work fine,But icon is very big on my Button is there any way to fit on button??

Comment: In this case you could assign icon to `BackgroundImage` property and set `BackgroundImageLayout` to `Stretch`. Or you can resize icon before assigning it. I'd go with first option.

Comment: Can u tell me how can i resize it??

Answer (score 1):

[System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox.Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonbase.image.aspx)